Resource consumption of Ettus USRP devices
I am desiring to work with one of the Ettus USRP devices. I want to learn about resource and power consumption of each default image files?
Is there any way to open the RFNoC designs on Vivado with GUI mode with using UHD?
Or how I can reach the power and resource consumption of default image files?

My expectation would be that the dominant factor in power consumption for the entire board will be the RF amplifiers.

@SimonRichter actually, don't think that's necessarily the case – daughterboard PAs don't put out more than ~ 20 dBm, the LNAs are run at "sensible" operating points. In the meantime, something like an X400 processes 1.6 billion complex samples in FPGA logic. I'd guess the majority of power would go into digital logic, followed by ADC and DAC power, the rest being analog electronics, tied with the network transceivers. But you raise an interesting point – I haven't done an analysis of the power rails of anyhting but an N210.

Power consumption: That will 100% depend on what you actually do with your signals, so this can't be a static number. This is a number logically impossible to calculate based on the image and its source code alone.
Resource consumption: At the end of the mapping stage in the image creation, you get a report that details that.
https://kb.ettus.com/Application_Notes has documentation on how to build images. You'll have to go and read at least AN-400, you'll probably want to read AN-121, and chances are good you want to read the documentation on the specific USRP model (there's many!) on there as well.
